# Difference between deterministic and nondeterministic Spark UDAF

Tags: apache-spark

I have a question about UDAF's behaviour in Spark .
Whats is the different between a deterministic and nondeterministic UDAF? I know that this flag indicates if same input produce same output, but I wonder if there are some different behaviour while processing the udaf.

Comment: This is up to execution plan, which these days can be affected by the user. In general deterministic flags on UD(A)F disable certain optimizations (for example computing only on unique values) and modification of the execution plan that could cause recomputing of expression in a different parts of the DAG.

Comment: Thansk, thats sounds very usufull. Could you share the source? I would like to know more...